# If $|H|=4$ and $gH$ has order 3 in $G/H$. Show that $K=H\cup gH\cup g^2H$ forms a subgroup of $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose that H is a normal subgroup of G. If $|H|=4$ and $gH$ has
order 3 in $G/H$. Show that $K=H\cup gH\cup g^2H$ forms a subgroup of $G$.

We know $g^3 \in H$, and that $K=\{h_1,...,h_n,...,gh_1,...gh_n,...,g^2h_1,...,g^2h_n\}$.
I am stuck here.
I don't know how to choose a general element in $K$ and then use the subgroup tests. I know $g^3 \in H$ will come in handy since $gh*g^2h'=g^3(hh') \in K$ , but how to choose a general element to account for elements that don't have a $g$?

Comment: Why have you got $\dots$ between $h_n$ and $gh_1$, and between $gh_n$ and $g^2 h_1$? Get rid of these and then you can see more clearly what a typical element of $K$ looks like.

Comment: Because it's a union, so they are jumbled up, no?

Comment: You are given that $|H|=4$ so you could just write down the 12 elements of K, preferably not jumbled up.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Thank you, I understand you can write out the elements but I would prefer solving a more general case. As in, we can just consider it luck that we have only 12. What if we had 100?
But even so, I've done it on paper and I am having trouble seeing the benefit in writing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.
Let $a=g^ih \in K$, for $0\leq i \leq2$

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/977993)

Comment: But that is the answer. I am asking "how to choose a general element to account for elements that don't have a g?" And the answer is the one I wrote.